# Angular 1.5, response status on error is always -1

Tags: angularjs, symfony, nginx, cors, angular-resource

I'm facing an issue when calling API, let me explain architecture first.

Whole font-end application os AngularJS 1.5 based, hosted on domains like below:
app1.mydomain.com, app2.mydomain.com, appN.mydomain.com

I have an API (Symfony2 based - FOS Rest) which is on:

api.mydomain.com

Server is Nginx, php5 (fpm), CORS open.

Now, lets describe problem:

Im calling an API endpoint for some data:

```
    var data = {someProperty: someValue};
    var $p = $resource($rootScope.apiDomain + '/some/endpoint', {}, {
        get: {
            method: 'GET'
        }
    }).get(data).$promise;
    var request = $q.all({request: $p});

    return request
        .then(function (response) {
            // code on success
        }, function (error) {
            // code on error
        });
```

Now let's say that server's response is ANY of 400's or 500's, then in ResponseError (interceptor) i've should get this code as an 'status' value

```
responseError: function (response) {
    if (403 === response.status) {  
        // something on 403
    }
    // do something on other codes
    return $q.reject(response);
}
```

No matter which response code is sent back from backend server, the `response` object contains following:

```
Object {data: null, status: -1, config: Object, statusText: ""}
```

However... i've seen [THIS ANSER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38690506/3648032) and this is basically what i do have now...

So:

1. Is there any way to solve such issue (i have, let's say full possibility in configuration of both back&front in any way)
2. If it's not "solvable" easily, then how to?

Comment: This looks like a CORS problem. What does the console say? What does the network panel say about the response?

Comment: Yeah itll be CORS.  Ensure you setup CORS on front and backend, theres load of info if you google but to get you started heres a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455045/angularjs-http-cors-and-http-authentication

Comment: Thanks for replies, basicly as i said, i do have CORS open as follows: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/aMHye04D)

@JBNizet console says correct ResponseCode (ie. 403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...

I've finally managed to make this working - nginx.opencors config

Solution:

(before)

`add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*";`

ResponseObject: `{data: Object, status: -1, config: Object, statusText: ""}`

(after)

`add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*" always;`

ResponseObject: `{data: Object, status: 403, config: Object, statusText: "Forbidden"}`